# select tag with invisible option

Tags: javascript, html, select

I want my select tag to be completely invisible, but still clickable, because I have a colored div representing the area that is clickable, and once clicked, the select options will be displayed. I have got it to the point where it is invisible, except for the initial text that shows before you click the select tag. I just need make that text invisible. Here is the code I have:

css of the coloured div:

```
.residentPanel {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    background-color:#65A3EB;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="residentPanel" style="background-color:#C991BE;" onclick="showSingleMeasurement()">
                <select style="left:0; width:100%;height:100px;background-color:transparent; -webkit-appearance: none;" id="allMeasurementsDropDownTablet" onclick="selectClick($('#allMeasurementsDropDownTablet'), measurementClick);"></select>
                </div>
```

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nf4zfrgq/)

I just need the black text in the purple div to disappear. Thanks.

Comment: A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) would be handy so we can tweak it ourselves and play around with it.

Comment: @GregL Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nf4zfrgq/) Thanks

Comment: Very cool idea, I see where you're going with that! +1!

Comment: Could you just change to opacity?   (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp)  That way the object is still there, but its opacity is set to 0 so you can't see it?

Answer (score 2):

add an empty option

```
<div class="residentPanel" style="background-color:#C991BE;" onclick="showSingleMeasurement()">
    <select style="left:0; width:100%;height:100px;background-color:transparent; -webkit-appearance:none;outline:none;" id="allMeasurementsDropDownTablet" onclick="selectClick($('#allMeasurementsDropDownTablet'), measurementClick);" value="">
         <option disabled selected style="display:none;"></option>
         <option>Durr</option>
         <option>jgbfj</option>
         <option>zzzzzz</option>
         <option>aaaaaa</option>
         <option>yyyyyy</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

---

### other

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="centered"></div>
      <select id="selectToCenter" onmousedown="this.value='';">
         <option value="1">Durr</option>
         <option value="2">jgbfj</option>
         <option value="3">zzzzzz</option>
         <option value="4">aaaaaa</option>
         <option value="5">yyyyyy</option>
       </select>
</div>
```

css

```
#content{
    position:relative;
    background-color:#C991BE;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1;
}
#centered{
  position:absolute;
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 18pt calibri;
  line-height:100px;
  background:red;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:-1;
}
#selectToCenter{
  height:100px;
  background-color:transparent;
  -webkit-appearance:none;
  outline:none;
  width: 100%;
  font: bold 18pt calibri;
  text-indent: 5px; 
  color:transparent !important;
}
option{
  color:black !important;
}
```

js

```
$('#selectToCenter').on('change', function () {
    $('#centered').text($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});
```

### <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/08yx0kbo/)</kbd>

Comment: I need the black text in the purple div to never show. In this example it does show when they select an option. Maybe what I want is not possible with a select tag. Thanks.

Comment: The text in the center is coming up black for me once an option is selected. Does it come up not black for you? I'm using Chrome for testing the jsFiddle. Thanks

Comment: I do not understand what you write

Comment: I need the purple div to never ever have any text on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

almost there:

```
color: transparent;
```

Comment: This makes the text for all the options invisible.

Comment: you could also do Opacity : 0; couldn't you?